# how to make installer create shortcuts to documents and folders of shortcuts (Windows 8)

Tags: installation, windows-8, microsoft-metro, nsis, shortcut

I develop an installer of library of COM objects using NSIS (Nullsoft installer) v2.0. The installer creates some shortcuts to documentation and folders of samples. On Windows 8, everything goes into the flat list in the tiles matrix of Metro UI. Moreover, only shortcuts to .exe files of samples appear in the list (no documents, no documentation, no links to Visual Studio solutions, etc).

Is it possible to fix this without rebuilding the installer from scratch? I would like to make the installer create a single tile with the name of my product, and clicking that tile should display the tiles of samples' folders, documentation, etc. Just like it occurs with folders of links in Start menu of Windows 7 and XP.

Comment: Please don't put fill our Start screens with your documentation & samples.  This is exactly what Microsoft is trying to prevent.

Comment: @SLaks I think you misunderstand.  He wants ONE tile that then opens a screen showing links to all his content.  This won't clutter the start screen, but it doesn't fit with Metro either.

Comment: This isn't possible. There are no "folders" in the new start experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metro style doesn't allow for layered navigation using metro tiles.  What you will need to do instead is pin your main folder/application to the start menu so that your main folder opens on the desktop.  This will probably require a rewrite of your installer.

Comment: I still don't understand what I should do. My product is a COM library, it actually does not have any "main" .exe to run (it only has .exe files of samples). The main entry point is a documentation file. Even if I create a new installer, how should I go about my that? Do you mean the products like mine (components libraries) are no longer possible in Windows 8? The only advice would be go out of business?

Comment: You can't do the sort of tile navigation that you mentioned.  The best you can do is have a link which opens a folder on the desktop.  Like this: http://stevesofar.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/how-to-manually-pin-shortcuts-to-metro-in-windows-developer-preview/

Comment: I didn't have time to check this in detail. Once I do, I'll mark it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Finally got the time to check this. Immersive Application Shortcuts looked promising but for the time being seems there is no way to get this folder in NSIS installers :(

Comment: Yeah, an answer that heavily depends on a link and the link is broken.

Comment: @ThomasW. I removed the broken link and it still appears to be a valid answer.